# Glossaries - how to deal with auxiliary files in another directory using MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, glossaries, auxiliary-files

To keep my main folder clean, have redirected the auxiliary files using the `-aux-directory=.\auxiliaries` command in `LaTeX` and `PdfLaTeX` ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFQDB.png)). However, when making the glossaries, TeXstudio gives the following message:

> Auxiliary file 'main.aux' doesn't exist. Have you run LaTeX?

Pasting the same command into the  `Makeglossaries` field yields the same result.

How can i make glossaries find the aux files?

Minimal working example that works when the aux files are in the main directory, but not when the aux files are redirected into a subfolder:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper, english]{report}
\usepackage[toc,symbols,nomain]{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{pi}{type=symbols,name={\ensuremath{\pi}},sort=pi, description={ratio of circumference of a circle to its diameter}}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printsymbols[title=List of Symbols]
\section{Text}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\gls{pi}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

[[compilation commands in TeXstudio][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFQDB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFQDB.png)

Comment: Coud you post a minimal (non-) working example?

Comment: @Bernard i updated my question with a working example.

Comment: my guess is, you have to expand the searchpath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running on the command line `makeglossaries --help` one can see the options it knows. Beside other the -d switch:

[image]

So add `-d auxiliaries` to the call.

Comment: I didn't know that you could do that. Thank you, it works perfectly now!

Comment: Hi. did you solve this problem? Can you send back the example?